# Probability distribution of the difference of two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X,Y,$ and $Z$ be random variables, with $Z=X-Y$ and $z,y \geq 0$

$$P(Z \geq z, Y \geq y)=P(X-Y \geq z, Y \geq y)=P(X \geq y+z)$$

Is that correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, you have $\{X-Y\geq z\}\cap\{Y\geq y\}\subset\{X\geq y+z\}$ but the other inclusion does not hold.

So you have just an inequality between the probabilities, not equality in general.